# Could someone explain this notation?(set theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

The expression is :

$$\bigcap_{s \in S}L_s$$

Where $s$ means student, $S$ is the set of all students and $L(x, y)$ means "$x$ likes $y$". So where I'm reading it from ("How to Prove It A Structured Approach") it says that it translates to:

"The set of all students who are liked by all students."

I don't get the $L_s$ part. Isn't it more correct to write it like:

$\bigcap_{s \in S}[L(s, s)]$ ? Or something like that. Isn't $L_s$ ambiguous?

Comment: I would've interpreted $L_s$ as the set of all pairs $(x,y)$ in $s$ that have the relation L.

Answer (score 1):

From the English description it becomes clear that $L_s=\{x\mid L(s,x)\}$ and so $$\bigcap_{s\in S}L_s=\bigcap_{s\in S}\{x\mid L(s,x)\}.$$ If $x\in L_s$ then $s$ likes $x$, so if $x\in \bigcap_{s\in S}L_s$ then it means $x$ is liked by every $s$ in $S$. It follows that $\bigcap_{s\in S}L_s$ is the set of all such $x$ in $S$ which are liked by every $s$ in $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Without having the specific book on hand, it sounds like for a given student $s$, $L_s:=\{x:L(s,x)\}$. $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$ means the set of elements shared by every $A_i$ (the $\bigcap$ notation doesn't make much sense if it's not followed by a collection of sets). So if $L_s$ is as I suppose above then $\bigcap_{s\in S}L_s$ is the set of students that are liked by every student.